# how to scale image between 2 views with given coordinates in android

Tags: android

In my application I have a requirement to animate an image (this image view has an arrow set as source).[image]

I am unable to figure this out how I can achieve this.To solve this i got x and y coordinates of second view that is rectangle after getting coordintes i am setting 
scaleX() of image view that is purple line but I am not geeting desire out put because it stretches to the whole screen along x-axis

here is the code what i tried is

```
int x = (int) imageView.getX();
imageView2.setScaleX(x);
```

here imageview is rectangular box and imageview 2 is the purple line

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont try with scenes? It's exactly what you need.

http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/scenes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the correct output when using the above code. Scale is defined against initial dimensions. And you would need to use something like this

`dist = box.getX() - circle.getX()`

and your scale would be

`imageView2.setScale(dist/distInitial)`

where `distInitial` you compute it at creation time using the `dist` formula.

You might need to change the position because it is scaled around the center of it (i.e. a smaller scale shrink margins to center of image)

You might want to perform this operations using a `Canvas`. It might be more efficient.